# Any way to retrieve values from variables different functions? c++

Tags: c++, function, arguments

For example, I have a function that turns a binary number into decimal and another function which turns a decimal number into a binary number. Then I have another function that checks if the binary and decimal numbers match (both represent the same number). These three operations have to be separate functions. I need the value from the binary function and the value from the decimal function in the checker function to check them.

Could I use the return value? I don't want to use global variables. Sorry if this is a dumb question as I am new to functions.

Comment: Did you try to use the return value?

Comment: I'm curious what your function is that "turns a binary number into decimal ?"

Comment: If you end your question with code showing us what you've tried (and how it failed), it might be easier for us to address the core issue.

Comment: Without a concrete example, it's hard to answer. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58785281/edit) to add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like int double and return the output. It will work as normal variables but the calculations can be done in it.

```
int TurnIntoDeciman(/*any parameters you   need*/)
{
     /*calcuations, variables anything that you  need*/
return /*decimal number or any value/variable      that will be set to the function*/
}
```